# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ids' when running kivy app

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a app that captures 30 images a second from the webcam in kivy.

But when I run it, it give me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ids'
```

Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string('''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: True
''')


class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        '''
        Function to capture the images from the camera
        '''

        camera = self.ids['camera']
        camera.export_to_png("IMG.png")
        print("Captured")

    event = Clock.schedule_interval(capture, 1 / 30.)


class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


TestCamera().run()
```

This code brings up the error but deleting `event = Clock.schedule_interval(capture, 1 / 30.)` fixes that error but I need that line of code.

**Question:**

So, how can I fix the error so that I can capture images from the webcam and store them?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ids'` is already telling you where to fix it. I don't know if you have other code that interact with this. But `camera = self.ids['camera']` the `self` object is somehow created as float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following line

```py
event = Clock.schedule_interval(capture, 1 / 30.)
```

you are actually creating a class attr. assigning a [`ClockEvent`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_interval). As it takes a callback function/method with default arg. [`dt`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#module-kivy.clock) (delta-time, a `float`), in your case of

```py
def capture(self):
```

the arg. `self` is supposed to represent that (as being defined in class level).

So think for a moment, you want `self` to represent the current class instance and due to the construction it is supposed to be the `dt` arg., and that raises the `AttributeError`.

The solution could be like the following,

Declare that clock event from some method and call that method accordingly. Or define it within `__init__` as follows,

```py
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.capture, 1 / 30.)
        # Or just,
        # Clock.schedule_interval(self.capture, 1 / 30.)


    def capture(self, dt): # Note the added arg.
        '''
        Function to capture the images from the camera
        '''
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your callback function doesn't look for time-delta value as the kyvy.clock api calls for.  The line you should change is

```
def capture(self):

to

def capture(self, dt):
```

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html?highlight=clock#api

has the example code:

```
def my_callback(dt):
pass

Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 0.5)
```

Comment: still returns same error

Comment: I updated the response.  The issue should be the missing dt parameter in your callback

Comment: Now I getting: ```TypeError: capture() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dt'```